# "leading up to" the workshop

Tags: word-choice

(1) A lot of people have signed up for the upcoming workshop. I'm not sure if there are any more spaces available. I'm going to put you on the waitlist right now. I hope there'll be a spot for you. I'll give you a confirmation **leading up to the workshop**.

Does the highlighted phrase, leading up to, fit the last sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That phrase does not sound quite idiomatic to me (American English). But it is easy to understand the intended meaning: "I'll give you a confirmation (during the time period) leading up to the workshop."

It would sound more idiomatic (and more informative) to say something like, "I'll give you a confirmation *in the days* leading up to the workshop."

The current wording as you quote it seems to imply that the confirmation (the one they plan to send you) is the thing that "leads up to the workshop", which doesn't really make much sense.

I can imagine a native speaker writing that, but it doesn't really sound *good* to me.